# Run php in html pages

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, vesta

I know that many similar questions have been asked here, but none of the solutions to this problem helped me.

I add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm` entry to `.htaccess` file, but php is only executed at the root in index.html page, but in index2.html page at the root of the site no longer being executed, and accordingly in the directories also php is not executed.

Tell me, please, because of what such effect and how to solve this problem on a specific domain?

On the server installed Ubuntu and Vestacp.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you may need to use a stackoverflow in your mother language  because we (well I )  can't understand the context of your problem, here. `:-/`

Comment: Can you also show exactly ***which*** questions you tried and did not help you?

Comment: can you show us what the index2.html file looks like and the full `.htaccess` file? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for my English.
For example, I just output the value 1: http://www.mayones.com.ua/index2.html

Comment: @Jeick9 I deleted my answer.

Comment: Such a setup is generally a bad idea. Why would you want to do that? It creates a huge overhead for static html documents. Instead you want to leave the configuration as it is and take a look at request reqriting instead. That gives you much more flexibility when needed and also offers clean URLs without any "file name extensions".

Comment: @Jeick9 can you try and remove the `.php` and do `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` or `<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: @Jeick9 you can `@Niner` me back here, I have to stop staring at this question since I see no response or update to the post or your website.

Comment: I tried two options, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just disabled the "Proxy Support NGINX" in the control panel of vestacp and now php runs in html files.